# How do I assign a new value to an element within an object with Axios PATCH?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, post, axios

I'm using Axios.patch to change data in an API. 
This is how the API sort of looks:

```
"email": "string",
"phoneNumber": "string",
"mobileNumber": "string",
"temporaryAddress": {
  "address1": "string",
  "address2": "string",
  "address3": "string",
  "address4": "string",
}
```

It's simple enough for me to do it with the average values but when I want to apply a new value to one of the addresses It won't work and I'm not sure how the syntax should look, I tried a few things already but it won't update, and the most logical solution which is "adress.adress1: this.myAddress" is not accepted by the compiler. How do i PATCH/edit a new value when the element is inside an object? I want to change the value of address1, address2 etc.

I've tried to type it like this already but no success. 
"address: this.myAddress", "address: this.myAddress.address1" (doesnt give error, just doesn't update anything)  "address1: this.myAddress" (doesnt give error either but it updates nothing)

```
updateCustomer() {

  this.$axios.$patch('http://localhost:8381/customer/v3/PRIVATE/' + this.customerData.id + '/?auditUser=Updatus', {
      lastName: this.lName,
      phoneNumber: this.phoneNr,
      email: this.eMail,
      mobileNumber: this.mobileNr,
      firstName: this.fName,
      address.adress1: this.myAddress
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic YXBpdXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then(response => {
      alert("Information successfully changed!")
      this.updateCheck = false;
    })

  error => {
    alert("Type in the information correctly!");
    console.log("update error test");
    return false;
  }
}
```

I want the address1 value to be whatever my input is, but so far it's not updating or it throws a 400 error.

I tried it this way: "address: {address1: "blabla 2", address2: "blablabla 3", address3: "tester 4", address4: "mehmeh 5"}" and it compiled but it gave me the error message 400 "Bad Request". No clue what I need to do differently.

Comment: Have you tried this in postman?

Comment: Not the code itself, but I'm new to Postman so I've only been trying to use the PATCH function for the API that postman is also connected to. It only returns "Successfully updated customer!" so it works, but not sure how to PATCH separate data in Postman. Can I try my code there somehow?

Comment: postman does not run code, it sends requests. The idea is to see if the request works or not and that way you can know if the issue is with the request itself or the your code. I would recommend googling how to make a PATCH request with postman and going from there.

Comment: Oh sorry for the misunderstanding, yes I can send the request and it works successfully, so it should also work in my code...I'm just writing it in the wrong way and I don't know what the correct way is.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now!

This is how you reach the data within the "address" object.

```
address: {address1: this.myAddress1, address2: this.myAddress2, address3: this.myAddress3, address4: this.myAddress4}
```

It let me update the data now with PATCH.